# MSAL v2 and launchWebAuthFlow does not retrieve access token

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, azure-ad-b2c, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating a Chrome Extension with authentication in Azure AD B2C using MSAL2 and launchWebAuthFlow. In Azure, the app is registered as an SPA and the access token option is checked in Authentication section. The problem is that the authentication is done but the access token comes empty in the response. Is there a way to get it?

This is my code:

**Auth config**

```
const b2cPolicies = {
  names: {
      signUpSignIn: "b2c_1_susi",
      forgotPassword: "b2c_1_reset",
      editProfile: "b2c_1_edit_profile"
  },
  authorities: {
      signUpSignIn: {
          authority: `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi`,
      },
      forgotPassword: {
          authority: `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_reset`,
      },
      editProfile: {
          authority: `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_edit_profile`
      }
  },
  authorityDomain: "mytenant.b2clogin.com"
}

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority, 
        clientSecret: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
        scopes: ['User.Read'],
        redirectUri: "https://wpalojomizsavttlmcdieipalmiiozlqs.chromiumapp.org/"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    }
}
```

**Authentication function**

```
//msalInstance is received from an onClick function of a React component 
//and it's an object of PublicClientApplication

async function signIn(msalInstance) {
    const url = await getLoginUrl(msalInstance);
    const result = await launchWebAuthFlow(msalInstance, url);
    if (result) {
        chrome.storage.local.set({ accessToken: result.accesstoken });
    }

     msalInstance["browserStorage"].clear();
}

async function getLoginUrl(msalInstance, request, reject) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        msalInstance.loginRedirect({
            ...request,
            onRedirectNavigate: (url) => {
                resolve(url);
                return false;
            }
        }).catch(reject);
    });
}

async function launchWebAuthFlow(msalInstance, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
            url,
            interactive: true
        }, (responseUrl) => {
            const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
            if (!account) {
                if (responseUrl) {
                    msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise(responseUrl)
                        .then(resolve)
                        .catch(reject)
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

**Response**

[image]

As you can see, the accessToken is empty. It retrieves only the idToken but in my understanding, I can't use it to call an API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here are the scopes. You are using a MS Graph scope:

scopes: ['User.Read']

Which is not valid for a B2C solution. You will need to create another app registration, expose some scopes and acquire a token for these custom scopes.

If you check the below B2C MSAL.js example, you can see that you need to register a service app (to expose scopes) and a client app (that you use on the frontend to authenticate the users):

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-tutorial/blob/main/3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c/README.md